# I got Nans after subtracting data frame by a column data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe1(1273 rows x 40 columns), and i have another dataframe2 (1273 rows x columns 1).

I want to do subtraction between the 2 dataframes in order to have a new dataframe called AMP(1273 rows x 40 columns).

The subtraction must be like this ( for each row of dataframe1 - row of dataframe2)

I tried this function : dataframe1.sub(dataframe2, axis= 0 )

However, it does only subtraction on the first row and Nans on the others row.

Any suggestions about how this can be done?

Comment: Did you try `axis=1` for testing?

Comment: Wlecome to SO. Please read [mre]. Your questions should always include a minimal example of any data you are operating on/with - enough for us to be able to reproduce your problem. [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: `df.sub(dg.iloc[:,0],0)` - You need to *specify* the Series - the second DataFrame's column - for the subtraction.

Comment: Yes i tried axis=1

Comment: @wwii thank you so much for youranswer it works very well.
just a small favore can you expalin to me more your syntaxe.
I know that iloc let you select the all rows and the column 0, bur what do you mean about the last 0 that you add.

Comment: `DataFrame.sub(Series,axis=0)`